# Why is angular ng-repeat adding properties to my model?

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on an angular 1.2.x project and I have a list of radio button generated with ng-repeat and an array of objects.

markup

```
<div ng-repeat="answer in question.answers track by $index">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="answers" ng-value="answer" ng-model="myDataModel">{{answer.text}}
    </label>
</div>
```

array

```
[
    {
        "id":"0",
        "parentId":"0a4540dfec6549b4a3bd1b8fb6169d77",
        "text":"peanuts"
    },
    {
        "id":"1",
        "parentId":"deka9fkac6549b4a3bd1b8fb6169d77",
        "text":"cashews"
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "parentId":"0a4540dfec6asdf4a3bd1b8fb6169d77",
        "text":"brazil nuts"
    }
]
```

If I use pre tags to view my model as I select through the radios like this...

```
<pre>{{myDataModel | json}}</pre>
```

I see random properties climbing onto my data like this

```
{
    "id":"0",
    "parentId":"0a4540dfec6549b4a3bd1b8fb6169d77",
    "text":"peanuts",
    "spc_mXSzO":0,
    "idx_mXSzO":0
}
```

This is causing issues when I try to pre-select a radio button after loading data from my server. When my controller sets my model equal to one of the answers it doesn't have those properties so it doesn't select the radio. Additionally those property names change every time that I refresh the page so I'm not able to mock them. Where do these come from and what might I try to get around them when preselecting answers?

Comment: I've never seen Angular add anything like that. The only thing I've seen it add to the data are prefixed with a $. Can you create a plunkr that reproduces the problem? I tried but could not make your code work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I found the culprit. It was this library https://github.com/isteven/angular-multi-select

It attaches spc and idx properties for it's purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce what you're seeing either - here's a plunker with what you have above working:

http://plnkr.co/edit/1td3XtqQjMDk1XYBbjEn?p=preview

One issue which what you have is the ng-model directive in your input tag. You shouldn't bind to primitives directly on the $scope. Here's a good description of why:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

And an update to your code:

```
<div ng-repeat="answer in question.answers track by $index">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="answers" ng-value="answer" ng-model="myDataModel.myAnswer" />{{answer.text}}
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to reproduce this. I'm stumped. My best guess at this point is one of the 3rd party libraries that I'm using is acting crazy. I'll start pulling them out one by one and see if that's the case. I post back if I can find a way to reproduce this in plnkr.